# Checking if SSH protocol v1 is allowed

Tags: server, ssh, rkhunter

I ran rkhunter -c on a server an the warning that i got was the following:

```
Checking if SSH protocol v1 is allowed       [ Warning ]

Warning: The SSH configuration option 'Protocol' has not been set.
The default value may be '2,1', to allow the use of protocol version 1.
```

So i ran the command:

```
nano sshd_config
```

I added the line

```
Protocol 2
```

then re-ran the rkhunter command but received the same warning. What else can i try?

Thank you.

Comment: Die you restart the SSH server after the config change ?

Comment: Strange that this question was closed because it was too broad... 
Well, if you have `Protocol 2` in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, then open `/etc/rkhunter.conf` and change `ALLOW_SSH_PROT_V1=2` to `ALLOW_SSH_PROT_V1=0` and rerun `rkhunter`. 
From the config file, I cite: _If the 'Protocol' option has not been set in the SSH configuration file, then a value of '2' may be set here in order to suppress a warning message. A value of '0' indicates that the use of SSH-1 is not allowed._

Comment: I agree that question may stay open.
Explicitly you can try to SSH using protocol 1 or 2 with:    
```$ ssh -1 your_server   
SSH protocol v.1 is no longer supported ```
If you do `ssh -2 your_server`, this shall be only accepted